# Yii2 Kartik grouped dataview

Tags: php, yii2

Is there a way to page brake after a group? 
So instead of a group splitting over multiple pages it's all on one page?

If not can I access the current page data in the data provider to set the pagesize?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're talking about. Do you want to show all records on a single page?

Comment: If you take the example http://demos.krajee.com/group-grid-demo/3 Pavlova, Ltd. is split over page 1 and 2, I would like to group these all on one page so adding a 'page brake' after the group. I could alter the source data and make them grouped into an array however this makes it difficult to add the data back into the grid.

Comment: Interesting... I have never tried that, though. Still, you should provide what have you tried so far, perhaps I would be able to solve it.